# Outlook COMException

Tags: c#, com, outlook, outlook-2010, comexception

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException  ..Your server administrator has limited the number of items you can open simultaneously...

at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._AppointmentItem.get_UserProperties()

```
        var calendar = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

        if (calendar == null || calendar.Items == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var calendarItems = calendar.Items;

        if (calendarItems != null && calendarItems.Count > 0)
        {
            // Dont convert to LINQ or foreach please -> may cause Outlook memory leaks. 
            for (int counter = 1; counter <= calendarItems.Count; counter++)
            {
                var appointment = calendarItems[counter] as AppointmentItem;

                if (appointment != null)
                {
                    var userProperty = appointment.UserProperties.Find("myInformation");

                    if (userProperty != null && userProperty.Value == myValue)
                    {
                        return appointment ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Maybe its appointment.UserProperties.Find("myInformation") cause COMException?

Comment: thx for upvotes ) thats mean someone read it and find it good )

Comment: @Anubis1233 - I have posted my answer

Comment: thanks but I was already using restrict :/

Comment: @Anubis1233 you have exception with using Restrict? Have you created a question with your problem?

Comment: Yes I am having the exception with Rescrict. Sadly it is a random exception. I "fixed" it by cutting the result after the first 5 results. My Exchange admin has ensured me that this Error should not happen at this low number of entrys.

Comment: @Anubis1233 can you maybe post it as a question? With source code. Maybe you will become than the better solution that your one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  have found the solution for this. It isnt necessary to use `Find` cause `Restrict` make what I need.

```
...
string filter = string.Format("[myInformation] = '{0}'", myInformation);
var calendarItems = calendar.Items.Restrict(filter);
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure you release Outlook items as soon as you are done with them using `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()` instead of waiting for the Garbage Collector to kick in.

You also need to avoid multiple dot notation to make sure you do not get implicit variables (created by the compiler) that hold that intermediary results and cannot be explicitly referenced and released.

Comment: Great, thank you - I had the same problem, always closed the object but releasing the ComObject was the solution :)

Answer (score 3):

When done with an Outlook Mailitem close it then release it

```
For Each item As Outlook.MailItem In oFolder.Items
  '<process item code>

  'Close the item
    'SaveMode Values
    'olDiscard  = 1
    'olPromptForSave = 2
    'olSave = 0
  item.Close(1)

  'Release item
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item)
Next
```